# Excel, Unable to change the number format

Tags: number-formatting

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this one. It’s probably so simple, but its got me at a loss.

I have a Excel spreadsheet looking like this

[image]

Basically it’s a simple if statement if A1 = 10 then B1 will display 600, if not it will display a 0. It works ……but I can not format the number in B1, I right click Format cell, number, and select currency with 2 decimal places. No change . Colour, alignment, Boarder and fill works, its just the number type will not. B1 will feed other cells to workout a formulas. I need it in a currency format.

Does anyone know the answer to this.

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: Have you tried using just the number? (iow not the string)

Answer (score 0):

Use the integers instead of strings. Excel interprets your strings as... well... strings, and not numbers. Change your strings to numbers like this:

```
=IF(A1=10,600,0)
```

This should work and it should justify right again.